# HELP ... Storing temporary object information.?

Tags: apex

What is the best method to store the information ( be it a hash map or a list set ) on objects.

The requirement being that the user will do lot of iteration on the possible quotation of products and finally add them to a opportunity. In this case, The products under opportunity need not be created at the first instance, It needs to be added only when the user approves the addition.

One of the methods that I can think of, Is to have another inheritance object of product and use them.
Or
Store the necessary information on a text area field and parse them when we do the creation ?

Please suggest methods which is appropriate for this case ?

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce UI works best with straightforward SObjects. So one approach is to just create the child objects normally but add a picklist status field to indicate that the addition is "Pending Approval" or "Approved".

But if you are willing to build more of your own user interface elements, storing the child objects in JSON format in the parent object in a "Text Area (Long)" field works as as [JSON.serialize](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) and [JSON.deserialize](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize) are available in Apex. But you'll have to do more work in your page to allow children to be added and removed and presented.